# How to scroll to playing track in windows media player's library?

Tags: windows-media-player

I have a huge library in Windows Media Player, and after a while playing I don't know which track is playing right now nor I can guess it. The highlight given to the playing track is also very subtle and in a huge list it's hard to detect it.

Is there any key or trick to know which music is playing right now?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable WMP's playlist pane (visible on the right-hand side), you should be able to see the currently playing track. The current track is highlighted and the list is always automatically scrolled by WMP to show the current track in the visible area.

To enable the playlist pane in Library Mode, click the `Play` button near the top. In Now Playing mode, right-click on an empty area and select `Show list` from the menu.

Additionally, the [Windows Media Player Plus!](https://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in can show the currently playing track in WMP's title bar.